# exec: "com.docker.cli": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: docker

I am getting this error when `docker-compose up` on one of the containers only.

```
exec: "com.docker.cli": executable file not found in $PATH
The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-c', 'docker logs -f f6557b5dd19d9b2bc5a63a840464bc2b879d375fe72bc037d82a5358d4913119'" failed to launch (exit code: 1).
```

1. I uninstalled and reinstalled docker desktop@2.3.0.5 on Mac
2. `docker-compose build` from scratch
3. other containers are running
4. I get the above error.
5. It used to be running. I am not sure why this is happening. I know that I upgraded docker from I think 2.3
6. also I think I received an update on my mac

Dockerfile

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn:python3.8
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./app /app/app
#COPY config.py /app/app/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
    postgresql:
        container_name: postgresql
        image: postgres:12
        ports:
            - "5433:5432"
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
            - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
        volumes:
            - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    fastapi:
        build:
            context: ./fastapi/
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./fastapi/app/imgs:/app/app/imgs
        ports:
            - "1001:80"
        depends_on:
            - postgresql
        env_file:
            - .env
    pgadmin:
        container_name: pgadmin
        image: dpage/pgadmin4
        environment:
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=pgadmin4@pgadmin.org
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin
        ports:
            - "5050:80"
        depends_on:
            - postgresql

    solr:
        build:
            context: ./solr/
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8983:8983"
        volumes:
            - data:/var/solr
volumes:
    data:
```

**update:**
It worked when I downgraded to docker desktop 2.3.0.4

Comment: I had the same issue and downgrading to 2.3.0.4 helped me as well. I created this issue: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4956
But then I updated it again via automatic updates to version 2.4.0.0 and the second time it kept working.

Comment: I think dockerfile and docker-compose config are not related to the problem and should be excluded from the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Updated Answer**:

Since [VSCode Docker 1.14.0](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/releases/tag/v1.14.0) you can now set the Docker executable path in the settings, which should help in most cases.

[image: VSCode Setting, Docker Path]

---

**Old Answer** (Option was removed from Docker Desktop):

The Desktop Docker Version 2.4.0.0 is working for me after I did deactivate the feature `Enable cloud experience`. You can find it under `Preferences` --> `Command Line`.

[image: Cloud Experience]

---

If you are still experience the problem, you may try a clean remove and install of Docker and also **make sure that Docker is actually running**, see other  possible solution(s) here.

---

History of GitHub Issues:

- https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/4956
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/2366
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/2578
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/2894
- Status (2021-06-22): VSCode Version 1.57.0 seems to have fixed the issue again.

Comment: I confirm this solution works using MacOs Catalina 10.15.6, with Docker Desktop 3.1.0

Comment: Does not work for me on Manjaro 21.3.7 Ruah with Docker Desktop 4.12.0

Answer (score 9):

You might get the following error message simply because you did not **start `Docker`** just yet

```
exec: "com.docker.cli": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Comment: so how to start it

Answer (score 6):

In my case the problem was I had installed and then crudely removed the docker compose cli. This resulted in the above error to start popping up.

I got the compose CLI back using instructions from https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/#install-the-docker-compose-cli-on-linux and running (as root):

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/compose-cli/main/scripts/install/install_linux.sh | sh
```

This fixed it for me.

Note: I would not recommend installing docker-compose cli to fix this issue, but to share some insights in case this is applicable to you as well.

Comment: This fixed it for me, and IMO should be the solution.

Comment: @apokryfos the disclaimer note you've put in your answer creates a lot of questions

Comment: @AteSomebits to clarify what I mean. I encountered this problem because I had installed docker-compose and then removed it improperly and this solution should work in that case. If you never installed docker-compose in the past then installing it now will probably not solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that docker CLI is installed not just docker desktop on Linux. YOu can install it using:

```
sudo apt install docker.io
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who may come with similar error for e.g.

> exec: "com.docker.cli": executable file not found in $PATH Current
> PATH : XXXXXX

You may need to **install the docker engine separately**, atleast true in my case (using Arch linux). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update: The "cloud experience" no longer exists even as an experimental feature in Docker Desktop v3.2.1. This should no longer be an issue.

If you continue to see this problem on a newer version, you will need to downgrade to Docker v3.1.0, disable the cloud experience feature, then upgrade to the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue.  Was fixed after starting the upgraded docker first, then running this command.

```
dostarr@DOSTARR-M-38LF ~ % docker run busybox
exec: "com.docker.cli": executable file not found in $PATH
<started docker>
dostarr@DOSTARR-M-38LF ~ % docker run busybox                           
dostarr@DOSTARR-M-38LF ~ %
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to run `minikube tunnel`, and since I didn't want to re-install anything, I ended up running it from the docker bin path (on Windows it's in 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin') and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Docker Desktop is [colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima), container runtimes on macOS (and Linux) with minimal setup.

```
# Homebrew
brew install colima docker

colima start
```

Now, you can use the docker commands as before.

For docker compose commands, you have to install:

```
brew install docker-compose
```

Answer (score 0):

On Debian I had the exact same error after a manual binary installation.

Even if my binary was inside the `/usr/bin` which was already in the PATH, it still was not working. Running `/usr/bin/docker` was working though.

It turned out that I had the binary in both `/usr/bin/docker` and `/usr/local/bin/docker`.

I had to have instead a symlink between these 2 paths, rather than 2 independent binaries.

So I removed the `/usr/local/bin/docker` file and added instead a symlink from the `/usr/bin/docker`

```
ln -s /usr/bin/docker /usr/local/bin/docker
```

Answer (score -1):

if already have installed docker, it may not have started. So type in terminal,"docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started" and it should solve the issue.